# Java - .class not found issue

Tags: java

I have following code,

```
class AA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long ll = 100 ;

        AA1 a1 = new AA1() ;

        if(ll == 100) // Marked line
            long lls [] = a1.val(ll);

    }
}

class AA1 {

    public long [] val (long ll1) {
        long [] val = new long []{1 , 2, 3};
        return val ;
    }

}
```

which executes properly without the marked line. However, gives error ".class expected" with marked line. Can anybody help me what is the problem and how to solve this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically this is a simplified version of your problem:

```
if (condition)
    int x = 10;
```

You can't do that in Java. You can't use a *variable declaration* as the single statement in an `if` body... presumably because the variable itself would be pointless; the only purpose would be for the side effect of the expression used for the assignment.

If you *really* want the pointless declaration, use braces:

```
if (condition) {
    int x = 10;
}
```

It's still useless, but at least it will compile...

EDIT: Responding to the comment, if you need to use the variable *outside* the `if` block, you need to declare it *before* the `if` block, and also make sure it's initialized before you read the value. For example:

```
// Note preferred style of declaration, not "long lls []"
long[] lls = null; // Or some other "default" value
if (ll == 100) {
    // I always put the braces in even when they're not necessary.
    lls = a1.val(ll);
}
// Now you can use lls
```

Or:

```
long[] lls;
if (ll == 100) {
    lls = a1.val(ll);
} else {
    // Take whatever action you need to here, so long as you initialize
    // lls
    lls = ...;
}
// Now you can use lls
```

Or possibly use a conditional expression:

```
long[] lls = ll == 100 ? a1.val(ll) : null;
```

Comment: so, how to solve this ? I simplified my code. Actually, the code returns dynamic array. And I don't know about it's size. If I use braces I can't use it other place, outside if. I want to use outside.

Comment: @Arpssss: If you want to use it outside the `if` statement, you need to *declare* it outside the `if` statement (before it). You'll need to make sure you've definitely assigned it some value before you try to use it though. Consider what should happen if the `if` condition is *not* true.

Comment: OK. So, I have to declare outside, and assign inside.

Answer (score 2):

As Jon Skeet points out, this (1):

```
if(ll == 100)
    long lls [] = a1.val(ll);
```

won't compile because it's using a declaration as a single statement.

This (2):

```
if(ll == 100){
    long lls [] = a1.val(ll);
}
```

will compile because the compiler doesn't really care what's inside the `{}` -- it's a block, as far as the `if` is concerned. It's also pointless because it's equivalent to (3):

```
if(ll == 100)
    a1.val(ll);
```

However, when I see (1), it usually looks like what was actually meant is:

```
long lls [];
if(ll == 100)
    lls = a1.val(ll);
```